# If $f$ and $f'$ are integrable, then $f'$ has integral $0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have the problem

> Prove that if $f$  and $f'$ are Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, then $\int_\mathbb{R}f' = 0$, where $f'$ is defined everywhere.

Honestly, not sure where to start. I had the idea to perhaps use the fundamental theorem of calculus $f(x) = \int_0^x f' + f(0)$ and take limits as $x$ goes to $0$ and trying to work from there. However, I'm not sure that the theorem holds in this case. Any help getting started is appreciated!

Comment: Please say precisely what you (or your instructors) mean by the hypotheses.

Comment: Note that if $f$ is differentiable (a.e.), then $f$ is absolutely continuous and the traditional Fundamental Theorem of Calculus does hold. But I believe you need $f'$ defined, in the traditional sense, everywhere.

Comment: This is the way that it was stated, and I am working under the assumption that $f'$ is defined everywhere. If I may ask, what sort of kinks arise if this only holds a.e.? EDIT: then the counterexample below shows this does not hold. nevermind!

Answer (score 2):

As a counter-example you can take a compactly supported function, say $f(x)=x^2$ over $[0, 1]$.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the answer to this question really depends on how you interpret the question. This answer assumes that $f'$ means the derivative of the $L^1$ function $f$ which is defined almost everywhere.

Comment: $f'$ is not defined at $1$ so this is not a counterexample.

Comment: But if you take a bump function, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $\int_{\Bbb R} f' = 0$, indeed. I believe that if $f$ is everywhere differentiable, the result is correct.

Comment: If you're going to do distributions properly, then $f'(x) = 2x \chi_{[0,1]}(x) - \delta(x-1)$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(x) \, dx = 0$

Comment: @Sam Thank you for the counterexample. While I'm assuming differentiability is assumed to be everywhere, this helps me get an idea of what goes wrong if this assumption is weakened.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'$$

Taking the appropriate limits...

$$0=f(\infty) = f(0) + \int_0^\infty f'$$

$$0=f(-\infty) = f(0) + \int_0^{-\infty} f'=f(0) - \int_{-\infty}^0 f'$$

$$\therefore \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'= \int_{-\infty}^0 f' + \int_0^\infty f'=f(0)-f(0)=0$$

Where we needed $f$ to be Lebesgue integrable to know it tended to $0$ on the tails, and $f'$ to be Lebesgue integrable to rearrange those integrals.

Comment: We need *both* $f$ *and* $f'$ integrable to conclude that $f$ tends to $0$ on the tails; there are integrable functions that do not have limits at $\pm \infty$, or are even unbounded as $x$ tends to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Yes actually I can see there would be such examples, thanks.

Comment: @JohnFernley Thank you for the answer! I have one question: how is it that we can conclude that $f$ tends to infinity as $x$ does?

Comment: $f$ will probably not tend to infinity a x does? We want it to tend to $0$ if that's what you meant.

Comment: I guess I could use that a principal value integral of $f'$ tends to the integral of $f'$, so outside some $[-R,R]$ the integral is less than some $\epsilon$ which puts a limit on variation in $f$, and an $|f|$ so constrained with a finite integral cannot be converging to anything except $0$. Not happy with this level of rigour...

Comment: @JohnFernley oops yes, sorry, a mistake on my part. I indeed meant "how do we conclude that $f$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$?"

Comment: I thought it must tend to $0$ for $\int |f|$ to be finite, but as @Hurkyl indicated this is not true. See my comment above for an approach?